# Why am I getting this warning during compilation in VS 2013 after moving to MVC 5 from MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I solve it?
I see this type of conflicts in a number of assemblies...

1) C:\DEV\xyz\source\xyz.Web\Web.config.xslt

2>  `Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Helpers, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll] to Version "3.0.0.0" [C:\DEV\xyz\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to drop the reference to System.Web.Helpers.dll and then re-add it with the recommended version. You may have to browse for the newer version instead of just picking it from the MS libs.

Another, though more ham-fisted, option might be to create a new project/solution from scratch as MVC5 and move your files into it. But this is much more involved and accomplishes pretty much the same thing as the first suggestion.

Comment: What I am seeing is that multiple versions of the same dll is being referenced by different 3rd party components!!